# Flutter SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code I'm trying to use `Image.network()` to access this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KZGlobalTeam/map-images/public/thumbnails/kz_ladderall.jpg and I've figured out I'm having this exception because the website refused my emulator's connection while other links such as https://picsum.photos/250?image=9 works fine.

I have tried to use proxy from v2rayN but still does't work. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up acessing the link via a proxy website, it was just a firewall problem within China

Answer (score 0):

First, try

```
  Flutter clean
```

And then if this did not work then. Use This way :

```
 Image(image:NetworkImage(url))
```

I hope this would solve your problem

Comment: thanks but I'm sorry that doesn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, using `Image.network`, maybe you are doing something wrong.
Please check once again.

```
 return SizedBox(
      height: 100.0,
      width: 100.0,
      child: Image.network('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KZGlobalTeam/map-images/public/thumbnails/kz_ladderall.jpg'),
    );
```

[image]